# How to think in automata theory or some recommendations of resources related to this?

Tags: automata, reference-request

Recently, I find that automata theory is very useful in computer science, it is used in many fields, such as computer network, digital design, computer architecture and operating system, even we can construct  KMP algorithm using the theory of automata. I really wonder if there are any books or articles summing up these applications. Furthermore, I want to find books which introduce the idea of analyzing  problems  related to the subject of computer using the theory of automata.

Can anyone recommend some resources for me?